# get objects colour in if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I have two objects that move around the screen (`Ball` & `Target`) I am trying to build a if statement so that when the `Ball` hits the `Target` the `Target` will take on the colour of the `Ball` (Black).

Problem is the applications background is changing and not the target colour. can some one see where I have gone wrong?

**code**

```
if (Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Target.Bounds))
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to set the color of the `Target`, not `this` (which is apparently pointing to your main window).

```
if (Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Target.Bounds))
{
    Target.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else
{
    Target.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Ahh simple enough, Thanks you.